# How to allow ICMP calls to a Load balancer in AWS beanstalk app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ping, amazon-elb, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, icmp

I would like to add the ability to open ICMP to the load balancer that is in front of my Eleastic beanstalk app, and do it in the .ebextensions. Can this be done?

I was able to do it by adding it to the inbound ports on the service group on the load balancer, but want to make sure it still gets opened if EB gets rebuilt.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done using configuration options.

1) Create a security group with the rule ALL ICMP allowed from whatever you want to ping from.

2) Then you need to create a file in your .ebextensions folder with the following content:

```
option_settings:
    - namespace: aws:elbv2:loadbalancer
      option_name: SecurityGroups
      value: id-of_your_security_group
```

where id-of_your_security_group is the id of the security group you just created. 
Refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html
for more information.

I wouldn't recommend to do this though, as being able to ping the load balancer doesn't really implies that the service is up.